# Python Local and Global Variables

Tags: python

```
def spam():
    print(eggs)
    eggs = 13

eggs = 12
spam()
```

This gives the error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'eggs' referenced before assignment`

But this does not:

```
def spam():
    print(eggs)


eggs = 12
spam()
```

Why?

Comment: Because the first version contains an assignment to `eggs`, it is assumed to be a local variable. The second version contains no assignment to `eggs`, so it is assumed to be a global variable.

Comment: The reasoning is, you don't want `eggs` suddenly changing from global to local in the middle of your first function; and you don't want it to silently modify a global variable unless you have declared your intention to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, when you do `eggs = 13`, the function tries to find the definition within it's scope, assuming it as a local variable,and since no such variable is defined within the function, `local variable 'eggs' referenced before assignment.` exception is thrown.

In the second example, since no such assignment is present, `eggs` is taken from the global scope, which is `eggs=12`, hence no such exception is thrown here

To resolve this issue, you need to assign a local variable `eggs` within the function. Here only the local variable `eggs` is referenced to and changed, the global variable `eggs` is the same.

```
In [40]: def spam(): 
    ...:     eggs = 12 
    ...:     print(eggs) 
    ...:     eggs = 13 
    ...:     print(eggs) 
    ...:  
    ...: eggs = 12 
    ...: spam() 
    ...: print(eggs)                                                                                                                                                                
12
13
12
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you by clicking the tick next to the answer @YashGupta Also consider reading up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work